# Sort array of objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a array of makes as follows:

```
const makes = [
{id: "4", name: "Audi"},
{id: "5", name: "Bmw"},
{id: "6", name: "Porsche"},
{id: "31", name: "Seat"},
{id: "32", name: "Skoda"},
{id: "36", name: "Toyota"},
{id: "38", name: "Volkswagen"}
]
```

And I want to sort that array based on another array:

```
const preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'];
```

What I do now is as follows:

```
const preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'];

const makes = [
{id: "4", name: "Audi"},
{id: "5", name: "Bmw"},
{id: "6", name: "Porsche"},
{id: "31", name: "Seat"},
{id: "32", name: "Skoda"},
{id: "36", name: "Toyota"},
{id: "38", name: "Volkswagen"}
]

const mainMakes = []
const otherMakes = []

makes.map(make => _.includes(preferred_makes, make.name) ? mainMakes.push(make) : otherMakes.push(make))

console.log(mainMakes)
console.log(otherMakes)
```

But is there any better way? Can I sort `makes` to show those `preferred_makes` as first elements of the array?

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ctuwrnoj/1/)

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Your approach is bad from every point of view, did you know what's the purpose of function `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: You don't need lodash. `['x'].includes('x') === true`

Comment: @AluanHaddad you don't need to compare a boolean result against a boolean value.  You can either negate it or simply use the result.

Comment: @Ele I was just illustrating that it returns a boolean result in what I thought was a concise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparison function should be able to do this.

```js
const preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'];

const makes = [
  {id: "4", name: "Audi"},
  {id: "5", name: "Bmw"},
  {id: "6", name: "Porsche"},
  {id: "31", name: "Seat"},
  {id: "32", name: "Skoda"},
  {id: "36", name: "Toyota"},
  {id: "38", name: "Volkswagen"}
]

const sorted = makes.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  // Convert true and false to 1 and 0
  const aPreferred = new Number(preferred_makes.includes(a.name))
  const bPreferred = new Number(preferred_makes.includes(b.name))
  
  // Return 1, 0, or -1
  return bPreferred - aPreferred
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with the by one incremented indices and take a default value of `Infinity` for not found names. Then sort by the delta of the values.

```js
var preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'],
    preferred = preferred_makes.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = i + 1, o), {});
    array = [{ id: "4", name: "Audi" }, { id: "5", name: "Bmw" }, { id: "6", name: "Porsche" }, { id: "31", name: "Seat" }, { id: "32", name: "Skoda" }, { id: "36", name: "Toyota" }, { id: "38", name: "Volkswagen" }];

array.sort((a, b) => (preferred[a.name] || Infinity) - (preferred[b.name] || Infinity));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` to make two arrays without the requirement for sorting:

```js
const preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen','Audi'];
const makes = [{id:"4",name:"Audi"},{id:"5",name:"Bmw"},{id:"6",name:"Porsche"},{id:"31",name:"Seat"},{id:"32",name:"Skoda"},{id:"36",name:"Toyota"},{id:"38",name:"Volkswagen"}];

const [mainMakes, otherMakes] = makes.reduce(([a, b], { id, name }) => ((preferred_makes.includes(name) ? a : b).push({ id, name }), [a, b]), [[], []]);

console.log(mainMakes);
console.log(otherMakes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

To make it even faster, you could `Set.prototype.has` instead of `includes`:

```js
const preferred_makes = new Set(['Volkswagen','Audi']);
const makes = [{id:"4",name:"Audi"},{id:"5",name:"Bmw"},{id:"6",name:"Porsche"},{id:"31",name:"Seat"},{id:"32",name:"Skoda"},{id:"36",name:"Toyota"},{id:"38",name:"Volkswagen"}];

const [mainMakes, otherMakes] = makes.reduce(([a, b], { id, name }) => ((preferred_makes.has(name) ? a : b).push({ id, name }), [a, b]), [[], []]);

console.log(mainMakes);
console.log(otherMakes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort by the [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if the index is there otherwise use [`String.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). No real need for lodash really:

```js
const makes = [ {id: "4", name: "Audi"}, {id: "6", name: "Porsche"}, {id: "31", name: "Seat"}, {id: "32", name: "Skoda"}, {id: "5", name: "Bmw"}, {id: "36", name: "Toyota"}, {id: "38", name: "Volkswagen"} ] 
const list = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'];

let result = makes.sort((a,b) => {
  let i = list.indexOf(a.name)
  return i < 0 ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name) : list.indexOf(b.name) - i
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can generate a dictionary of the original `index` by the car's make (`indexByMake`) using `_.invert()` to get an object of `{ [car make]: original array index }`, and map the values back to numbers.

Use `_.orderBy()` to sort the array, and use the values from `indexByMake` according to the `name`:

```js
const preferred_makes = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi'];
const array = [{ id: "4", name: "Audi" }, { id: "5", name: "Bmw" }, { id: "6", name: "Porsche" }, { id: "31", name: "Seat" }, { id: "32", name: "Skoda" }, { id: "36", name: "Toyota" }, { id: "38", name: "Volkswagen" }];

const indexByMake = _.mapValues(_.invert(preferred_makes), Number);

const result = _.sortBy(array, ({ name }) => indexByMake[name]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```